# Extracting of the arithmetic root of arbitrary degree

Tags: python, math

How to extract an arithmetic root of arbitrary degree in Python?
I know that algorithm:

```
z = pow(x,(1/N))
```

Is this correct?
Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed the way to go. However, you need to use `1.0/N` to ensure float division (unless `N` is always a float):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(27, 1/3)
1.0
>>> math.pow(27, 1.0/3)
3.0
>>> math.pow(27, 1/3.0)
3.0
```

You could also use [`from __future__ import division`](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html) to make `/` the "regular" division operator (for integer division you would then use `//`):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(27, 1/3)
3.0
```

Instead of `math.pow(x, y)` you could also use the `x ** y` operator:

```
>>> 27**(1.0/3)
3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ** operator

```
    >>>x = 32
    >>>n = 5
    >>>x**(1.0/n)
    2.0
```